# Read a file using "read()" function

Tags: c, malloc, buffer, fopen, eof

i'm studying C, and I need to read a text-file, but I can only use "write, malloc, free, open, read, close".

That's my code:

```
#define MAXCHAR 10000

int open_fp(int check)
{
    char *int_vector;
    int fp,len;
    int i,j;
    char buffer[MAXCHAR]; 

    if(check == 0) //standard list
    {
        if((fp = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY)) != -1) //check if the fp is opened. -1 = error
        {
            printf("\n%d\n",fp); // DEBUG FUNCTION
            sleep(1);

            if (!(int_vector = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeof(char))))
            {
                printf("\nWrong allocation\n!"); // DEBUG FUNCTION
                return(0);
            }
            len = read(fp,int_vector,MAXCHAR);

            for(i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                printf("%c",int_vector[i]);
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            printf("File error!");
            return (0);
        }
        
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Now my question is: As you can read here,

```
 char buffer[MAXCHAR];
```

i've created static buffer, but i would like create a dynamic buffer which allow me to resize the buffer according to the number of the chars in the text file, but i don't know how... someone have a trick ?

Comment: You can allocate with `malloc()` and resize with `realloc()`. If you are "not allowed" to use `realloc()` then you can allocate another buffer of the right size, copy the data, and `free()` the first buffer.

Comment: ...or you can start with a small (say 1024 bytes) buffer, and keeping reading and reallocating until the file has been read. Then you have max 1023 bytes unused.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thank you man for the reply! Unfortunately i can not use realloc function! Thank you anyway for the reply!!

Comment: I mentioned something you can do instead.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes man, i saw it right now !

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Mostly because it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("File error!");`  This tells the user (almost) nothing about the problem and error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest calling: `perror( "your error message" );`  as that will output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("File error!");
            return (0);` and similar code sequences:  this is failing to notify the calling function that 'this' function failed. (typically, a returned value of 0 indicates success)  suggest returning -1

Comment: Hi user! Thank you for the reply. That printf is gonna be overwritten with the correct syntax, infact in this exercise, i can not use "printf" but only "write" function that is locate on "unistd.h". I just use this pritf in the debuging fase, for catch the exception and in the case looking for a fix. If you correctly close the file every time you open it, and that pritf is printed, is because another process is using it, or probably a bug in once of the lastest launch of the same program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your way of allocating memory is wrong in below line.

```
//This allocates only 2 bytes of memory, but you are trying to read 10000
if (!(int_vector = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeof(char))))
```

correct that line as below

```
//better to add one byte extra and store \0 at the end, useful in case of string operations
if (!(int_vector = malloc(MAXCHAR+1)))
```

and as far as your question is concerned, you dont need to reallocate memory in this particular case because you are just reading the bytes to buffer and printing.

a single `malloc` will suffice.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define MAXCHAR 100

int open_fp(int check)
{
    char *int_vector;
    int fp,len;
    int i,j;
    char buffer[MAXCHAR]; 

    if(check == 0) //standard list
    {
        if((fp = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY)) != -1) //check if the fp is opened. -1 = error
        {
            printf("\n%d\n",fp); // DEBUG FUNCTION
            sleep(1);

            if (!(int_vector = (char*)malloc(MAXCHAR)))
            {
                printf("\nWrong allocation\n!"); // DEBUG FUNCTION
                return(0);
            }
            //not doing memset on purpose because only limited bytes are accessed.
            while(len = read(fp,int_vector,MAXCHAR))
            {
                printf("\n **number of bytes read is %d **\n",len);
                for(i=0;i<len;i++)
                {
                    printf("%c",int_vector[i]);
                } 
            }
            printf(" At last LEN = %d\n", len);

            //free the memory at the end
            free(int_vector);
            int_vector = NULL;
            close(fp);// better to as fd
        }
        else
        {
            printf("File error!\n");
            return (0);
        }
        
    }
    return(0);
}

int main()
{
    open_fp(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey @sravs! Thank you man. I didn't understand the part

Comment: Hey @sravs! Thank you man. I tried to understand the part:
            while(len = read(fp,int_vector,MAXCHAR)), but i didn't...if the buffer is equal to 1024, does the program only read the first 1024 chars in the text file (?)

Comment: nothing to discuss, i've tried this code and it works. I understood how did you use the lenght in read. i've just changed a little stuff

while ((lenght = read(fc, &c ,1)))
 {
  i++;
 }

-where fc is the name of the file
-c is declared as char
-1 is the byte to read, for parse the text file, byte by byte!

Comment: the function: `sleep()`  needs the header file: `unistd.h` for the prototype

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (!(int_vector = (char*)malloc(MAXCHAR)))`  in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  Suggest removing the cast

Comment: regarding: `while(len = read(fp,int_vector,MAXCHAR))`  the function: `read()` can return 0 (effectively EOF) and can return -1 (effectively some I/O error occurred)   When `read()` returns -1, that `if()` will evaluate as TRUE and the body of the `if()` will be executed.  This is not desirable.  ALSO, `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Answer (score 0):

ehm, If you forget to set `realloc` to it as well, here is some sample code for reallocation (dynamic resizing buffer)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main () {
       char *str;
    
       /* Initial memory allocation */
       str = (char *) malloc(15);
       strcpy(str, "tutorialspoint");
       printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);
    
       /* Reallocating memory */
       str = (char *) realloc(str, 25);
       strcat(str, ".com");
       printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", str, str);
    
       free(str);
       
       return(0);
    }
```

Comment: I think its better to use different variables for `malloc` and `realloc`, in case `realloc` fails, we will loose data allocated by `malloc`

Comment: @niek, sravs, thank you for the reply! Unfortunately i can not use realloc function!!